# Satisfiabilty 2-sat

Tags: logic, satisfiability, propositional-logic

Im trying to work out whether the following clause is satisfiable:

```
{x, y},{x,¬y},{¬x, y},{¬x,¬y},{x, z},{x,¬z},{y, z},{y,¬z}
```

My basic understanding is to work this out, you must give each literal a true or false assignment to work out if each clause is satisfiable so:

x=1,
y=1,
z=1,

```
{1,1}, {x,0}, {0,1}, {0,0}, {1,1}, {1,0}, {1,1}, {1,0}
```

Therefore the clause `{x,y}` and `{x,z}` are satisfiable?

I also heard you can switch the statement so:

x=1,
y=0,
z=1,

This means `{x,y}` is not satisfiable.

If we changed z to 0 as well `{x,z}` would not be satisfiable. What really confuses me here is when the truth assignments are changed, neither clauses are satisfiable.

Where am I going wrong?

Answer (score 4):

You seem to assume that both literals in a clause must be true in order to satisfy the clause. However, it is sufficient that one of them is true. So with your first assignment all clauses but `{¬x,¬y}` are satisfied.

You also mix up some terminology:

- A clause is a single group of literals like `{x,y}`. What you are trying to satisfy overall is a group of clauses or a formula.
- When you are considering a specific assignment of values, you talk about clauses that are "satisfied", not "satisfiable". Satisfiability is a property of the formula as a whole. (A single clause is always satisfiable.)

PS: Since your formula only uses 3 variables it is feasible to try out each possible assignment of values in order to see if the formula is satisfiable.

Comment: Specifically, "satisfiable" means "*can* be made true by *some* assignment"; "satisfied" means "*is* made true by *this* assignment".